# compare array function return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hei guys, i'm trying to compare two arrays... Correct order (which length may vary) and User order (which length also may vary). What i have tryed :

```
function checkArrays(arrayA, arrayB){
    var temp;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
    {
        if(arrayA[i] == arrayB[i]){
            temp = temp + "<span class='green'>" + arrayB[i] + "</span> ";
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp + "<span class='red'>" + arrayB[i] + "</span> ";
        } 
    }

    inputParagraph = document.getElementById("userInput");
    inputParagraph.innerHTML = temp;
    //inputParagraph.innerHTML = inputParagraph.innerHTML.replace(/undefined/g, '');
}
```

`console.log(correctOrderArray);
 console.log(userArray);
 console.log(checkArrays(correctOrderArray, userArray);` return :

```
[1, 8, 20, 39, 72]
[1, 39, 20, 8, 72]
undefined<span class='green'>1</span> <span class='red'>39</span> <span class='green'>20</span> <span class='red'>8</span> <span class='green'>72</span>
```

My question is: From where that undefined when i returned conosle.log for this function???

The solution i've found is the last line commented from function, but it's lame to pass over this situation like so...

Comment: your temp variable is initially nil. First initialize  the variable and then add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you only declare variable `temp` but never initialize it with a value, so it is `undefined` until set a value.

What happens next is that you are concatenating `temp` with the string `<span class='green'>` or `<span class='red'>`. Unary `+` operator performs string concatenation if at least one of the operands is a string and converts other to string if necessary. But since `temp` is not a string yet (its type is `undefined`) then type conversion occurs from `undefined` to `String`. The rule of such conversion is that it yields the string `'undefined'`. That's why you get this result.

You should initialize `temp` with an empty string:

```
var temp = '';
```

#### Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/ce6tyan2/

Comment: Correct! but i found a better way using temp as array and push in it if condition or if not condition checked. Another thing, user can let userArray empty so i need to use for with userArray.length :) But thx for your answer, u were right!

Answer (score 1):

You temp is uninitialized, maybe that is causing the issue. Check it!

Answer (score 1):

Set your temp to an initial value. `var temp='';`